Transformer models for contextual word embedding in large datasets
I'm interested in using contextual word embeddings generated by a transformer-based model to explore the similarity of certain words in a large dataset.
Most transformer models only allow up to 512 tokens of input. So presumably I would need to break the dataset down into individual sentences (<512t) & feed them into the model. That would give me a list of word embeddings per sentence. I'm struggling to understand how I could best translate this list into meaningful embeddings per word across the whole dataset.
The immediately obvious approach would be to find the average embedding for each word. However, the point of contextual embedding is that it can identify different uses/meanings for the same word. 'Bank' as a noun and 'bank' as an adjective may have very different embeddings and therefore I'm not sure that the average would have a great deal of meaning. Is this a genuine concern? Is there a better approach?
In such a use case is there any value in using a contextual transformer model over a static one?


You can use embeddings form OpenAI API which allows up to 32k tokens. Also many opensource large LLMs have at least 8k tokens per model. 2. usually you take embeddings from the last layer, which already includes attentions to the context. 3. The quality of the embeddings should be evaluated using metrics on test dataset and not based on your trust to the specific models


Thank you for the suggestions but I'm looking at data with significantly more than 32k tokens, so I would still have to split the dataset and deal with the issue of how best to handle multiple embeddings per word.
